# How can I automatically load fixtures into my development database but not my production database when using django-nonrel?

Tags: google-app-engine, fixtures, django-nonrel

I'd like to load some test data into my development db but not put it into my production db.

In django you can create database-specific fixtures using this mechanism: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#database-specific-fixtures

It is possible to do something similar with django-nonrel?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the local datastore is separate from the production datastore.